# Where is the main event loop in the Firefox source code?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am looking through the [Firefox source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/) and trying to determine the source for the main loop that executes all the event handlers in Javascript.

I have looked over [this overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Directory_structure) of the directory structure, but I still cannot find the event loop.

**Which source lines should I look at to find the main event loop?**

Update: I am building and running Firefox on Linux x86_64.

Comment: When firefox is compiled for which platform?

Comment: @i_am_jorf, On Linux x86_64.

Comment: JavaScript engines are incredibly complex beasts, especially when you consider things like JIT compilation, worker threads, and so on - so there is no single "main event loop" - it's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I worked on the Chakra JavaScript engine between 2014 and 2015 while at Microsoft.

Firefox's JavaScript engine is called SpiderMonkey, and can be considered a separate project - and it can be used by other applications too ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine ).

Modern JavaScript engines are JIT-based: they don't interpret code in a giant loop - instead they compile JavaScript functions into native code - effectively their own program, and this dynamically generated program will have its own event flow - but it isn't necessarily a "loop" - and there isn't necessarily "one" individual program either - because it depends on the JavaScript hosting environment: a web-page can run multiple JavaScript "workers" simultaneously (acting as different threads - this is beyond JavaScript's current asynchronous model). Also note that "Firefox" is just a wrapper around Gecko - and Firefox runs multiple Gecko instances side-by-side, and in different runtime worker processes.

That said, pretty much all JIT JavaScript engines still retain their interpreters - Chakra does - because the JIT process takes a while, so they will initially run script in interpreted mode for immediate results - and the interpreter part of the engine may as well be a completely independent JavaScript engine implementation (ignoring the parser and standard library components).

It's been almost 18 months since I last worked with the Chakra source code ([it's open-source now](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore)) but from what I remember (and without breaking my NDA) the only real main "loop" in Chakra was the interpreter loop (a giant `switch` statement for the current opcode `enum` value) - the event handlers were handled through asynchronous IO - so it's actually up to the Chakra host to provide the asynchronous IO functionality - so in short, there is no "event loop". I'd be surprised if Firefox's SpiderMonkey or Chrome's V8 didn't work on the same basis.

Comment: I'll edit the question later tonight,  but I guess what I'm trying to determine is the code path that invokes the handlers. If the js is JIT before use,  there must be some code that invokes the compiled code.

Comment: @merlin2011 This sounds like an XY Problem ( http://xyproblem.info/ ) - what is your actual objective? If you're wanting to learn more about JavaScript engines then there are better ways than focusing on this single aspect.

Comment: Here's my actual objective: https://superuser.com/questions/1205185/is-it-possible-to-disable-javascript-without-reloading-the-page-in-modern-firefo

Comment: I asked about finding the event loop because the other question is too broad for SO, since the are multiple source level modifications may achieve the desired goal.